# R: sf plot size of color key

Tags: r, plot, r-sf, color-key

There a way to adjust the `height` and `width` parameters of colorkey legend of `plot.sf`, as is possible in `spplot`?

```
library(sf)
nc_sf <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
plot(nc_sf["AREA"], main = "sf", key.pos = 1,
     key.size = lcm(1.2)) # Only adjust the height of key (on bottom side)
                          # How adjust the width ?
```

[image: plot-sf]

```
library(sp)
nc_sp <- as(nc_sf, 'Spatial')
spplot(nc_sp, "AREA", main = "sp",
       colorkey = list(space = "bottom",
                       height = 0.5, width = 1))
```

[image: sp-plot]

**edited**:

I trying something around the original code [plot.R](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/master/R/plot.R) at lines 203-211 and

```
if (! isTRUE(dots$add) && ! is.null(key.pos) && !all(is.na(values)) &&
                (is.factor(values) || length(unique(na.omit(values))) > 1) &&
                length(col) > 1) { # plot key?
            switch(key.pos,
                layout(matrix(c(2,1), nrow = 2, ncol = 1), widths = 1, heights = c(1, key.size)),  # 1 bottom
                layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1, ncol = 2), widths = c(key.size, 1), heights = 1),  # 2 left
                layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1), widths = 1, heights = c(key.size, 1)),  # 3 top
                layout(matrix(c(2,1), nrow = 1, ncol = 2), widths = c(1, key.size), heights = 1)   # 4 right
  )
```

changing the `widths`parameter and re-building the package. But don't work.

Maybe something around the function `.get_layout` ?

**re-edited**

My clumsy solution: rebuild the original function with some adjusts

```
my_plot.sf <- function(x, y, ..., col = NULL, main, pal = NULL, nbreaks = 10, breaks = "pretty",
    max.plot = if(is.null(n <- options("sf_max.plot")[[1]])) 9 else n,
    key.pos = get_key_pos(x, ...),
    key.widths = 0.1111, # new parameter
    key.size = .6666, # keep "key.size" instead of "key.heights" because it's called by another functions
    reset = TRUE) {
# original code of plot.sf until line 203 (show above), so I change the layout matrix
    switch(key.pos,
           layout(matrix(c(2,2,2,0,1,0), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = T),
                  widths = c((1-key.size)/2, key.size,(1-key.size)/2),
                  heights = c(1, key.widths)),  # 1 bottom
           layout(matrix(c(0,1,0,2,2,2), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = F),
                  widths = c(key.widths, 1),
                  heights = c((1-key.size)/2, key.size,(1-key.size)/2)),  # 2 left
           layout(matrix(c(0,1,0,2,2,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = T),
                  widths = c((1-key.size)/2, key.size,(1-key.size)/2),
                  heights = c(key.widths, 1)),  # 3 top
           layout(matrix(c(2,2,2,0,1,0), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = F),
                  widths = c(1, key.widths),
                  heights = c((1-key.size)/2, key.size,(1-key.size)/2))   # 4 right
    )
 # remainder of the original code
```

my_plot.sf

```
my_plot.sf(nc_sf["AREA"], main = "my_plot.sf", key.pos = 1,
           key.size = .5, key.widths = .1666)
```

[image: my_plot.sf]

Comment: Yes, there are several examples of doing this in the `sf` [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf5.html#color-keys)

Comment: @camille - I think the OP is specifically after adjusting the width. In their question they demonstrate changing the height. I don't think there are examples of changing the width in the vignette

Comment: I see. I took a look at the same section of the plot.R file. It seems like the width of the legend is scaled to fit neatly in the bbox, the same as the map. Maybe you could make the plot and the legend separately, and then stick them together in the same viewport with `grid` or `cowplot`? But that might become more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: You could ask on the [project's github page](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues)

Comment: Thanks! I opened this issue: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/731 and committed your suggestion to a branch called "keywidth"; I suggest to continue the discussion there. I removed key.size; we now have key.length and key.width.

Answer (score 1):

sf 0.6-3, submitted to CRAN, has the facilities for doing this.